# UnsatisfiableError on conda package install

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am trying to do this command to install a package:
`conda install -c eumetsat ropp-eum`

However it returns the following errors:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \ 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                                                                                                                      

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package sqlite conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> sqlite[version='3.13.*|>=3.20.1,<4.0a0|>=3.22.0,<4.0a0|>=3.23.1,<4.0a0|>=3.25.2,<4.0a0|>=3.25.3,<4.0a0|>=3.27.2,<4.0a0|>=3.29.0,<4.0a0']
Package libnetcdf conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libnetcdf[version='4.4.1.1.*|4.6.1.*,>=4.6.1,<5.0a0|4.6.2.*,>=4.6.2,<5.0a0']
Package pip conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> pip
Package libstdcxx-ng conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
python=2.7 -> libstdcxx-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package git conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> git
Package libnetcdf-cxx4 conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libnetcdf-cxx4[version='4.3.*|4.3.0|<=4.3.0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> tk[version='8.5.*|8.6.*|>=8.6.7,<8.7.0a0|>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package libgfortran-ng conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
Package netcdf-fortran conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> netcdf-fortran[version='4.4.4.*|4.5.1.*']
Package libnetcdf-c conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libnetcdf-c[version='4.4.*|4.4.1|<=4.4.1|<=4.4.1.1']
Package eccodes conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> eccodes[version='>=2.8.2']
Package ncurses conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> ncurses[version='5.9.*|6.0.*|>=6.0,<7.0a0|>=6.1,<7.0a0']
Package ca-certificates conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> ca-certificates
Package libgcc-ng conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.3.0']
python=2.7 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.2.0|>=7.3.0']
Package libffi conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> libffi[version='3.2.*|>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
Package readline conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> readline[version='7.*|>=7.0,<8.0a0']
Package ecmwf-grib-api conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> ecmwf-grib-api[version='1.16.0|1.23.*']
Package bufrdc conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> bufrdc[version='000405|<=000409|>=000409']
Package hdf5 conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> hdf5[version='1.8.15.*|1.8.15.1']
Package netcdf-cxx4 conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> netcdf-cxx4=4.3.0
Package zlib conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> zlib[version='1.2.*,>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0|1.2.*|1.2.8']
python=2.7 -> zlib[version='1.2.*|>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
Package openssl conflicts for:
python=2.7 -> openssl[version='1.0.*|1.0.*,>=1.0.2l,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2m,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2n,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2o,<1.0.3a|>=1.0.2p,<1.0.3a|>=1.1.1a,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1b,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1c,<1.1.2a|>=1.1.1d,<1.1.2a']
Package ecmwf-eccodes conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> ecmwf-eccodes[version='2.7.*|2.8.*|>=2.8.2']
Package libnetcdf-fortran conflicts for:
ropp-eum -> libnetcdf-fortran[version='4.4.*|4.4.4|<=4.4.4']
```

Which is really weird since some of them only concern python or ropp-eum and there are no interactions in their specifications, and some of the things that are supposedly conflicting do not look like they actually conflict.

I have tried both reinstalling anaconda3 and moving to anaconda2 and both give the same error. I even tried installing all the packages with versions that were listed as correct and I still got the same error.

I am using this on an aws server which runs on linux

Is this a problem on my side or the package side?

Comment: First, do you really need Anaconda? Why not Miniconda and then install only what you truly need? Second, do you really need to install this in your **base** env? Creating a new env is so simple: `conda create -n my_env -c eumetsat ropp-eum`.  Third, you probably need the Conda Forge channel also, i.e., `-c conda-forge`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had not realized that I had the option of setting up an env with just that package installed, I am new. That got it working though.